# L2スイッチとL3スイッチの違いについて

Tags: network

このようなネットワーク構成においてルーターを再起動すると cluster間での通信ができなくなってしまいます。
[image: 構成図]

ルーターとクラスター間では L2スイッチ（AT-GS950）があるのですが、これを L3スイッチに変更することで
ルーター再起動時でもクラスター間通信は継続することができるのでしょうか？

私はてっきり L2スイッチにも MACアドレステーブルがあってできるものかと思っていたのですが...

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/4236)のような気がします。装置交換よりも通信できない理由を調べるべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: L2=データリンク層, でスイッチングするので, Ethernet-networkであれば MACアドレスにてスイッチします。(単独では)ネットワーク層は管理外。L3=ネットワーク層まで考慮するのが L3スイッチでは？ (何をどう疑問に思っているのかもう少し記述がほしいところ)

Answer (score 0):

L3レベルの話であれば「ルータが落ちたらクラスタ間通信が死ぬ」ということはないので、もっと上のレイヤで何かが起きているんでしょう。L2スイッチをL3スイッチに変えたら改善するかもしれない(「ゲートウェイとの疎通がとれなくなると崩壊する」みたいなシステムなら)し、そうでないかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

> L2スイッチにも MACアドレステーブルがあってできるものかと思っていたのですが...

L2スイッチもMACアドレステーブルはあります。むしろ、L2スイッチは、MACアドレスに基づいてデーターの転送を行います。

> ルーター再起動時でもクラスター間通信は継続することができるのでしょうか？

同じセグメントであれば、クラスター間で通信は可能だと思います。

一つ気になったのが、クラスターと言われる機器ですが、仮想Pアドレスなど割り振っていませんか？全て実IPアドレスですかね？

これだけの環境では、詳細が分からないのですが、取り合えず、
一度、L2スイッチ、クラスター機器を再起動し、MACアドレステーブルを綺麗にしてみては
いかがでしょうかね。